# Required Sample Project with Cucumber + TestNG + spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, cucumber, testng

I do not have much experience with spring boot. I have been just wondering about is it possible to use Cucumber + AbstractCucumberTestNG runner and spring boot in the same project? If yes then could you please provide me a simple project that can help me to understand the things in a better way.

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/spring Replace JUnit with TestNG. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/spring-txn For the right version check out the git tag of your Cucumber version